# Http Web Server - big response packet issue C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, web, protocols

I have been making a HTTP web server for mainly a application generated uptime monitor but wanted to expand it so its more general use. A problem I am having with it is when a client requests for an image (for example) that is 1MB+ I don't know how to split the image data up to fit inside the MTU size of packets.

Below is the code I am using to send the data. (StreamWriter AutoFlush is enabled)

```
        private void sendResponse(Stream stream, string fileLocation, bool useGzip, string contentType, string ResponseLine, bool CloseConnection, string server)
    {
        writer.Write(ResponseLine + "/r/n");
        writer.Write("Server: " + server + "/r/n");
        if (CloseConnection == true)
            writer.Write("Connection: close" + "/r/n");
        else
            writer.Write("Connection: keep-alive" + "/r/n");

        //if (useGzip == true)
        //    writer.WriteLine("Content-Encoding: gzip")
        writer.Write("Content-Type: " + contentType + "/r/n");
        writer.Write("Content-Length: " + stream.Length + "/r/n");
        writer.Write("Accept-Ranging: bytes" + "/r/n");
        writer.Write("" + "/r/n");

        byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Flush();
    }
```

Also, in Wireshark the capture shows 500+ packets of max size with continuation or tcp segment, does HTTP have a way of splitting up big responses into multiple packets without tcp segmentation?

Solved - Using sockets instead of the TcpClient class worked a treat and removing the stream overlays (BinaryReader/BinaryWriter)

Comment: Why don't you use HttpListener?

Comment: Why aren't you just sending the image back as binary data? Why are you trying to convert it to text? Surely this will mangle the image data in some way?

Comment: This is confusing. You have some misconceptions. Not sure where. Can you explain why you are not sending all data at once like `stream.Copy(Response.OutputStream)`?

Comment: if you want a small http server, why not just use node.js?

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand what an encoding is. Better research that.

Comment: Solved! I changed alot of the code so it didn't use stream writers and then changed from TcpClient to good old sockets and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should not care. Because the TCP socket will do that automatically. TCP streams are not limited by MTO and there is NO reason to not use the sockets.